# Signature for Visualforce to be stored to Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I tried this codes I found from a website :
http://teach-force.blogspot.sg/2014/02/capture-signature-on-ipad-using.html

There are no errors for the codes except that it is not able to be saved and it's not able to be sign using tablet or to exact ipad.

[image: After it I click save, it will prompt an error message instead..]

Comment: Do you have a question?  Perhaps you can outline what you've tried and what isn't working.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I would like to know why couldn't i save it when I followed it exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the Account ID as explained in the page. 
 https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/apex/CaptureSignature?id=001x0000003Mfxu 
The last field is the account Id in which the attachment of Signature will be saved.  
 Let me know in case you find any issue in this. It will work.  
 Please mark this explanation as answer if this helped you to resolve the issue/query.

Comment: This is not a link, it is an example of how you need to run the page. At the end of your url append the id for account

Comment: If this answer has helped in resolving your query, please mark this as answer. You can get back in case of any issues.